# Create table with composite attribute/columns in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have to create a Table in the SQLite database, however, I am unable to find the syntax where I can define composite attribute/columns while creating the table.[In this ER diagram, I have a composite attribute as a DateOfPurchase of the Bicycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCZ77.png)

So could some please help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: the last added field is a composite one with the 2 action fields !

```
  db = new sqlite3.Database('./event.db');
```

db.run("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO logTable (logfile, logdate, referto, area, status, action) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
      [entry["logfile"], entry["logdate"], entry["referto"], entry["area"], entry["status"], entry["action"]+entry["action2"]], 
    function(err) {
      if (err) {
         return console.log(err.message);
      } else {
          db.close();
     }

Its not while creating the tabel. It uses a existing field action